# "Ei, moço, você pode me dar uma informação" Até que ponto "moço" é ofensivo?

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas

No Brasil usa-se "moço" a torto e a direito: "ei, moço, pode me informar onde fica a Praça do Rossio?", "Ei, Maria, tem um moço aqui na porta querendo falar contigo", "Ah, tu és aquele moço que consertou o fogão?"  Geralmente o moço é jovem, mas às vezes usamos até para homens de meia idade. Podemos nos dirigir a um homem em Portugal chamando-o de moço sem ofendê-lo?  Qual seria essa situação?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não recomendaria de todo esse uso num vocativo. *Moço* (e *moça*) tem o seu quê de paternalista e de antiquado. Quando é usado, muitas vezes (mas nem sempre), é-o num tom algo entre o benevolente e o paternalista (e.g. "deixa lá a moça em paz").

Para nos dirigirmos a alguém e não ser potencialmente ofensivo, teria de ser uma pessoa bastante nova (certamente não um adulto). Diria que é até mais perigoso do que usar *você* em Portugal.

Usá-lo para referir um homem de meia idade ou mais velho seria, aí já não tanto ofensivo, mas simplesmente bizarro.

> Ei, Maria, está aqui à porta um moço que quer falar contigo.

Por outro lado, nesta outra frase "moço" é bastante neutro e a frase é adequada desde que se trate de uma pessoa jovem:

A seguinte é mais perigosa, mas por causa do tutear:

> Ah, tu és aquele moço que consertou o fogão?

Partindo do princípio que o tutear é adequado (o que é um pouco difícil de imaginar, mas podemos admitir por exemplo o contexto de uma relação patrão-criado tradicional), então "moço" também cairia bem.

A forma mais segura de nos dirigirmos a alguém que não conhecemos, como no contexto de pedir indicações, é omitir qualquer forma de tratamento, ou quando muito usar *o(a) senhor(a)* ou *a menina* (se a mulher for jovem):

> Desculpe, pode dizer-me onde fica o Rossio?

O Rossio provavelmente toda a gente sabe onde fica, mas se não tivermos a certeza de que o interlocutor sabe a resposta, o melhor será perguntar:

> Desculpe, sabe dizer-me onde fica o Rossio?

Comment: Acho estranho esse uso de "é-o".   Nunca vi seu uso tanto na língua escrita quanto falada.

Comment: @Centaurus é um pronome neutro de atributo — chamamo-lo assim na terminologia hispânica, ao menos, mas pode ser diferente na lusófona já que pelo visto na terminologia da gramática lusófona, não se sói usar o término *neutro*.  Fiz uma pergunta relacionado com o tema há um tempo.

Comment: "Diria que é até mais perigoso do que usar você em Portugal."  No Brasil, em situações formais, quando não há intimidade alguma,  seria apenas falta de educação.

Comment: "Diria que é até mais perigoso do que usar você em Portugal." Gostava que me explicassem o quão perigoso é usar "você" em Portugal.

Comment: @Oak Isso está fora do âmbito desta pergunta. Se estiveres interessado, podes submeter uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @Artefacto Por acaso não, visto que seria fora do âmbito deste .SE, visto que /NÃO/ é ofensivo usar 'você' em Portugal, e gostaria que me explicassem porque é que dizem que é quando... nunca ninguém disse isso.

Comment: @Oak "nunca ninguém"? Eh... Não vale a pena discutir então.

Comment: @Oak não acho que seja off-topic, de todo. Aliás, abriu agora mesmo [essa exata pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/o-uso-de-voc%c3%aa-em-portugal-%c3%a9-ofensivo). Vai lá vê-la. :)

Comment: @Centaurus 1. Eu nem reparei no "é-o". É perfeitamente natural para Portugal, se bem que denote um discurso mais cuidado ou refinado - da mesma forma que usar a palavra *denotar*. :) 2. Em Portugal "você" é formal, e "tu" é informal. À partida o "você" não tem intimismo nenhum, por cá; mas o "tu" *pode* ter.