# O uso de "você" em Portugal é ofensivo?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

[Nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1608/1798) e também nos seus comentários é dito que usar "você" em Portugal é considerado perigoso. Porém a discussão não prosseguiu e fiquei com dúvida se realmente é.

Não achei uma pergunta relacionada neste site. Só achei uma discussão [neste fórum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/c%C3%AA-em-portugal.2784121/#post-14070943) que afirma que em Portugal *"a palavra 'você' é ofensiva porque soa como tratamento de superior para inferior"*.
Como o comentário foi feito por um brasileiro e não por um português, continuei na dúvida.

No Brasil não é perigoso chamar alguém por "você". Pode ser considerado falta de educação caso não se tenha intimidade com a pessoa (especialmente ao se falar com pessoas mais velhas), sendo preferível usar as formas de tratamento "senhor", "senhora" e "senhorita" (apesar deste último eu não escutar muito ultimamente).
Mas depois que se tem mais intimidade, não há problemas em usar "você" (ou as suas formas reduzidas e mais informais "cê" ou "ocê").

E em Portugal, como é? Afinal, é ofensivo/perigoso? Depende do contexto?

Comment: Eu diria que o uso de você já está tão enraizado no Rio de Janeiro que não é mais considerado falta de educação entre desconhecidos de mesma idade.  Seria considerado falta de educação quando dito a alguém 20 ou 30 anos mais velho, ou a alguém com mais de 70 anos. (aproximações e impressão pessoal apenas).  Pode-se entrar numa loja e perguntar "você tem tal produto?" ou mesmo na rua "você sabe me informar...".  Quando eu era jovem, todos com mais de 40 anos eram considerados senhores por aqueles com menos de 20 anos.  E aqueles com aparência de idosos, são sempre "senhores" para os estranhos.

Comment: Quem poderia explicar o "perigoso" em questão, seria o Artefacto.  Infelizmente não o temos "visto" por aqui ultimamente.

Comment: Aqui em São Paulo também é parecido: entre pessoas da mesma idade não tem tanto problema usar "você" mesmo entre desconhecidos - até por falta de outra palavra, já que "senhor" pode ter a conotação de "idoso" e não costuma-se usar para pessoas mais jovens -  e "senhor(a)" acaba sendo usado para os mais velhos mesmo (em outros estados também percebo a mesma coisa, mas como não conheço todos, não sei dizer se é algo de abrangência nacional). Só evitei colocar tantos detalhes assim na pergunta porque o foco principal era o uso em Portugal. Agora não sei se deixo assim mesmo ou se detalho mais.

Comment: Eu sou brasileiro e até hoje não entendo esse voceísmo excessivo no Brasil, certo, tomou o lugar da segunda pessoa do singular, mas tomou também o lugar do pronome oblíquo! Vejo sempre frases como "vou fazer isto para você" ao passo em que em Portugal (ao usar o você) dizem "vou fazer isto para si", qual dos dois é o correto, já que no Brasil seria como dizer "vou fazer isso para a vossa mercê" enquanto que em Portugal, embora seja um pronome de tratamento atribui-se um valor de pronome pessoal (si)? Estou mais confuso do que nunca, portanto mesmo sendo brasileiro emprego o tu na escrita.

Comment: Que eu saiba o pronome oblíquo "si" é apenas reflexivo. Este uso aqui em Portugal de "para si" é coloquial. Claro, ele é tão popular que já não se pode considerar errado, mas não acho correto dizer que o "você" tomou o lugar do "si". Parece ser exatamente o contrário.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Portugal

Por ter trabalhado no atendimento ao público numa área que exigia muito formalismo, e sendo eu falante da variante europeia da língua, devo referir-lhe, parece-me, que no trato social em Portugal, há essencialmente três opções, aqui ordenadas do mais informal para o mais formal:

- tu
- você
- o senhor/a senhora

Estávamos liminarmente proibidos de usar a expressão `você` perante um cliente, usando sempre a terceira opção. Já perante uma pessoa mais velha com a qual tenho confiança, não ouso usar `tu` devido à assimetria de idades, mas o formalismo preconizado por `o senhor` também se revela desnecessário, assim sendo, `você` é um compromisso muito usado em Portugal entre o informalismo do `tu` e formalismo `do(a) senhor(a)`.

### Brasil

No Brasil há, parece-me, apenas duas variantes no trato social, sendo ambas conjugadas na terceira pessoa do singular, elas são, do informal para o formal:

- você
- o senhor/a senhora

E por conseguinte como referiu o outro comentador, ao informalismo preconizado no Brasil por `você`, corresponde em Portugal o `tu`. É devido a esta coincidência terminológica do uso de `você`, para situações de natureza formal de ordem distintas nos dois lados do Atlântico, que surge, no meu entender, a noção em Portugal de que fazer-se uso de `você` pode ser considerado desajustado. Para tal, julgo que também influenciou a cada vez maior influência da variante brasileira da língua, em Portugal.

Comment: Muito bom! De fato, atendimento ao público costuma ser mais formal e as empresas preferem usar apenas "senhor(a)". Já quanto ao uso de "tu" no Brasil, varia muito conforme a região (em algumas não é usado, em outras é, mas pode ter diferenças com relação ao uso de "você" ou ser equivalente, enfim, há muitas variantes e eu não saberia listar todas)

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: No Rio Grande do Sul o pronome 'tu' é usado com a conjugação na terceira pessoa do singular no lugar do 'você', e é o mais comum por lá. (Podendo ocorrer a conjugação correta). [tu gaucho](http://zh.clicrbs.com.br/rs/vida-e-estilo/noticia/2015/10/o-tu-esta-saindo-do-vocabulario-dos-gauchos-4890170.html)

Comment: @AndréLyra   O carioca, principalmente o das classes sociais mais baixas, quando usa o "tu", conjuga erradamente na terceira pessoa do singular.  Já com os gaúchos com quem converso quando vou a Porto Alegre, isso não ocorre.  Não sei se por serem bem letrados, usam a segunda pessoa do singular corretamente.  Em certas localidades de Santa Catarina também já observei isso.

Comment: João, no Rio de Janeiro usa-se ambos, mas eu considero "tu" uma forma mais íntima do que "você".  E acredito que muita gente pense assim. Só que o carioca, com raras exceções,  quando usa o "tu", conjuga-o erradamente na terceira pessoa do singular.  Soa feio e demonstra pouca instrução.

Comment: Não tem a ver com ser letrado ou não. É a variante linguística vigente no Rio. Soaria até pedante um carioca utilizar tu e conjugar sempre na segunda pessoa.  Em algumas regiões do Pará,  utiliza-se o pronome tu com a conjugação correta também, mesmo entre pessoas de pouco estudo.

Comment: Interessante meus caros, mas creio que no Brasil são raras as situações onde se conjuga o verbo na segunda pessoa do singular. Confirmam?

Comment: @AndréLyra Já tendo morando em PE em no RS e conhecido boa parte do Brasil atrevo-me a dizer que nesses dois estados se usa o 'tu' da mesma forma. Outra 'Coincidência' regional é o (ab)uso do imperativo

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira, segunda pessoa, tanto do plural como do singular, é muito raro de se usar. Na minha experiência pessoal, conjugar na segunda pessoa pode fazer com que o outro sinta-se ofendido por seu pedantismo gramatical. E segunda pessoa do plural praticamente só existe em teste de idioma

Comment: @Jefferson eu referi terceira pessoa, em relação ao Brasil.

Comment: Eu sou do Rio de Janeiro e corroboro o uso de _tu_ com conjugação de terceira pessoa do singular, ao mesmo tempo em que acrescento que não é usual utilizar _vós_ para a segunda pessoal do plural em oralidade -- usamos _vocês_ mesmo.

Comment: Além disso, tenho notícia que no Maranhão -- ou na capital São Luís ao menos, utilizam, em oralidade, não só _tu_ e _vós_ com suas conjugações seguindo a norma culta como também usam, em oralidade, mesóclise.

Comment: Eu sou gaúcho e posso confirmar: usamos muito o "tu" com a conjugação "errada" (terceira pessoa), até mesmo com quem não somos tão íntimos. "Você" é raramente usado; para contextos formais costumamos usar "o senhor"/"a senhora". Talvez isso não se aplique a todo o Estado do Rio Grande do Sul, mas certamente se aplica à microrregião de Caxias do Sul. E ah, para piorar a história, o imperativo afirmativo é conjugado normalmente (e.g. vai tu), mas o imperativo negativo é conjugado "erroneamente" (e.g. não vai).

Comment: *"julgo que também influenciou a cada vez maior influência da variante brasileira da língua, em Portugal.*    Julgo que também contribuiu...

Answer (score 12):

O uso de "você" não é adequado na maior parte dos casos em Portugal. Deve ter-se muito cuidado com o uso de "você".

Sou Português e em Portugal é preciso sensibilidade para usar a palavra você. Em situações normais normalmente é usado com quem não se tem muita intimidade, mas com quem também não se faz muita cerimónia. Usa-se no tratamento formal, de igual para igual ou de igual para inferior.

Por exemplo, sou professor universitário e trato os meus alunos por "você". O "tu" seria inadequado pela separação que há entre o papel de aluno e de professor, "o Senhor" seria inadequado porque os alunos são mais novos que eu, logo não têm direito a um respeito pela idade.

Quanto aos meus colegas, não os trato por "você". Ou trato por "tu", se são da mesma idade ou mais novos que eu, ou trato por "o senhor" ou "o professor" se são mais velhos que eu.

Em situações de grande intimidade (amigos) usa-se o "tu". Em situações de muita  cerimónia usa-se "o senhor / a senhora". O "você" deve ser usado com cuidado.

Resta dizer que "Você" vem de "vossa mercê", que é um título de grande deferência. Apesar de "vossa mercê" ser raramente usado hoje em dia, continua a ser de grande deferência. Já "você" passou a ser considerado uma forma de tratamento com algum distanciamento mas pouca deferência.

Comment: Como expliquei, em Portugal, `você` é o intermédio entre `tu` e `o(a) senhor(a)`. Eu trato a minha avó por `você`.

Comment: Eu tenho uma pergunta. Numa conversa que já dura  um tempo (meia hora), na qual a pessoa mais jovém já falou senhor or ou senhora várias vezes, não se diria você em um certo ponto? É preciso ficar falando O senhor não-sei-o-qué cada vez em vez do pronome você??

Answer (score 10):

Eu diria que ofensivo nunca é. Eu trato o meu patrão por *você*, a minha tia também trato por *você*. Mas claro que depende do contexto. Nós usamos o *você* quando queremos falar com uma pessoa com quem não tenhamos muita confiança (um desconhecido) e/ou que seja mais velho.

Na "alta sociedade" portuguesa as pessoas em vez de se tratarem por tu tratam-se por *você* porque acham que é mais "chique". E, se calhar, é dai essa confusão com o "perigoso".

```
pt-BR     | pt-PT
----------+---------------
você      | tu
senhor(a) | você/senhor(a)
```

Comment: *"quando queremos falar com uma pessoa que não tenhamos muita confiança"* - Qual seria exatamente o contexto desta situação? Alguém que acabei de conhecer e por isso ainda não confio o suficiente? Ou uma pessoa, mesmo que conhecida, mas com atitude "suspeita"?

Comment: @Hugo alguém que acabaste de conhecer e que, por exemplo, não seja da tua idade. Imagina ir pedir uma informação a uma pessoa mais velha, na rua, seria «Olá! Você pode-me ajudar?...». Se fosse da tua idade seria «Olá! (Tu) Podes-me ajudar?...»

Comment: "Eu diria que ofensivo nunca é." <-- Eu diria que pode ser ofensivo para algumas pessoas. Conheço muita gente que fica ofendida quando as trato por "você". Penso que essas pessoas focam ofendidas porque parece que estão a ser tratadas como se fossem velhas. Mas, não tenho a certeza.

Comment: @JorgeB. Acho que há pessoas que não gostam de "você tem uma caneta", e preferem "o sr tem uma caneta", mas depende do contexto, por exemplo se estiveres a falar com um prof teu, ou o presidente lol

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel eu acho que é por causa da relação formal que estás a criar. Não é *a palavra em si* que é formal, é mais o problema de estares a criar uma relação "formal" e potencialmente hierarquizada em vez de uma relação "tu-cá-tu-lá", menos formal, de "hierarquia mais horizontal". Podes *nunca* usar a palavra "você" ao falar, e a pessoa teria a mesma reação. Exemplo: a mãe do meu amigo insiste que a nora a trate por tu, mas a nora não consegue porque sente que isso seria uma falta de respeito - para enorme pena da sogrinha, que queria uma relação "mais de amigas" e menos de "sogra-nora".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sim, podia acontecer de as pessoas não quererem que as tratemos por você, mas daí a ser ofensivo vai uma certa distância. Nunca vi ninguém a ficar ofendido com isso, o que não quer dizer que não haja.

Comment: Há pessoas e pessoas. Pessoalmente, se me tratarem por "você", eu vou sentir-me muito incomodado mas não acho que seja ofensivo. No entanto, não se pode negar que há pessoas que levam isso ofensivamente.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel felizmente nunca conheci nenhuma, não fazia ideia que há pessoas que levam o tratamento por você como ofensivo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Infelizmente, conheço algumas, mas não consigo trata-las por "tu". Acho que "você" fica mal, mas "tu" fica muito pior.

Comment: Falando duma relação como aquela entre professores e estudantes, o meu professor de português anterior diria sempre, como o @Ismael, que _você_ fica mal (pode ser arrogante), mas _tu_ ainda pior (íntimo em demais); e que era muito normal os portugueses tentarem evitar os pronomes totalmente, usando em vez o nome da pessoa com o artigo definido. Por exemplo, se me estava a falar a mim, chamar-me-ia “o Janus”. Nenhuma das duas respostas aqui mencionam essa possibilidade – é que (já?) não se utiliza muito em Portugal?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet essa opção faz-me lembrar a alta burguesia portuguesa. Uma mãe da zona da foz do Porto (zona chique da cidade) diz para o filho "O Janus não se esqueça de levar dinheiro para o lanche...". A minha mãe diria, "Não te esqueças de levar o dinheiro para o lanche...". Mas não estou a ver ser usado por ninguém hoje em dia. Só por brincadeira...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet mas agora que falaste nisso, se calhar tendemos  evitar mesmo os pronomes, mas substituindo-os por nada. "Ó professor (você) pode chegar aqui?".

Comment: Sim, isso foi a ‘outra direcção’ que também nos ensinou, para se os estudantes tiverem que falar com o professor (ainda que ele diria mais _setor_ do que _professor_). E claro, a língua portuguesa sendo uma língua [_pro-drop_](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anáfora_zero) é sempre possível só usar o verbo sem nenhum pronome expresso – mas como só é na função de sujeito que se pode omiti-lo, isso não é sempre uma possibilidade (p.e. “Posso falar [contigo/com você/com o professor/…]”).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ou "Posso falar consigo", seria o que eu utilizaria.

Comment: @JorgeB. Uma má alternativa seria apenas dizer o que precisas. Por exemplo, em vez de dizer "Posso falar consigo?", apenas dizer "Preciso de falar sobre o meu trabalho.".

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel ia-me parecer um bocado estranho sem chamar o professor, "Ó professor, preciso falar sobre o meu trabalho.".

Comment: No Brasil se usa o tu no norte e no sul. Porque todo mundo fica dizendo que não? Parecem que não conhecem os "falares" das pessaos, ué.

Answer (score 4):

A utilização do termo "você" não está isenta de discordâncias.

O tratamento "você" é uma contração do termo "Vossa Mercê " e esta era a forma de tratamento a que tinha direito a burguesia, até finais do século XIX. 
Poderão considerar que era um tratamento prestigioso e é verdade. Raros eram os homens do povo que a ele tinham direito. Só que burgueses de classe média e média-alta **desejavam ser tratados como os nobres, por "Vossa Senhoria"** e sentiam-se **desconsiderados** quando não o eram.

Devido a este "desconforto Burguês" o termo "vossa mercê"  depressa se tornou popular como forma de **tratamento de desconsideração** mesmo entre as classes baixas.

Como o distrito do Porto e o Norte de Portugal eram e ainda são as regiões com mais burgueses (homens de negócios e comerciantes abastados) o termo "você" é ainda hoje rude e considerado sinal de má educação, sobretudo entre pessoas que não se conhecem. Naturalmente e respondendo à questão, ninguém no Porto (que é a zona do País que melhor conheço) se mostrará ofendido por ser tratado por "você", no entanto não é considerado uma forma de tratamento amigável ou agradável.

A região de Lisboa e Sul de Portugal onde o "vossa mercê" não sofreu uma carga tão negativa como no Porto (uma vez que a burguesia se concentrava mais a Norte) é ainda usado aqui e ali como forma de tratamento informal.

Em todo o caso é hoje em dia aceite e de bom tom não usar o tratamento "você" em qualquer parte do País, sendo preferível usar a supressão do sujeito se optar por não recorrer ao formalismo do "Sr." ou "Sra.".

Answer (score 2):

Eu encontrei uma [resposta lá no Yahoo!](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110814054259AAoQl1B) comparando "você" (português), "usted" (espanhol), "vostede" (galeco) e "vostè" (catalão):

> - Maior parte do Brasil: Você; Vocês
> - Parte do Brasil e maior parte de Portugal: Tu (íntima), Você (formal); Vocês (formal), Vós (íntimo)
> - Parte de Portugal e África: Tu (normal), Você (desrespeitoso); Vós (normal), Vocês (desrespeitoso)
> - Parte de Portugal, parte do Brasil e outras colônias: Tu (íntimo), Você (formal); Vocês
>
> Além disso, o tratamento como "você" tem mais de mil anos, tanto que a maioria das outras línguas ibéricas possuem equivalentes, como o Catalão (tu/vosaltres; vostè/vostès), Espanhol (tú/vosotros; usted/ustedes) e Galego (tu/vós; vostede/vostedes)
>
> A diferença é que na variante brasileira da língua portuguesa, a forma respeitosa fez com que a íntima caísse em desuso a partir de cerca de cem anos atrás para cá."

Agora, eu mesmo sempre chamo quem quer que seja de você: não acho que seja errado, até por terem pessoas que detestam o tratamento de o (a) senhor (a) [inclusive e principalmente, tem gente que diz que o Senhor é Deus e a Senhora é Virgem Maria!]!

Detalhe que na maior parte das áreas hispanofalantes, utiliza-se usted como equivalente a o senhor ou a senhora, inclusive e principalmente, na Espanha! Agora, acho esquisito que na América Espanhola inteira, ustedes seja plural tanto de tú / vos / voseo quanto de usted, eles simplesmente não utilizam vosotros! Muito mais simples e eficaz é o inglês, que aboliu de vez "thou" e "ye" (tu e vós em certas regiões da Europa antigamente), ficando somente com "you" mesmo (tanto para o singular quanto para o plural)!

A propósito: como se sentem os angolanos ao serem chamados de "vocês" (ou, também e; é; claro, cada um de "você"?)? Alguém daqui é de Angola?

Answer (score 2):

Conheci uma portuguesa, quando participei de uma candidatura aqui em Florianópolis por uma vaga de emprego, a empresa era portuguesa, e informalmente eu lhe perguntei como o pronome você era usado em Portugal. Segundo ela, lá não se usa você, se usa tu, o pronome você lá segundo ela é cafona de se falar. Eu, nas músicas, filmes, documentários, nunca vi um português falar você, sempre falam tu.

Answer (score 2):

As pessoas levam você a mal como se os estivessem a mandar à me*da. Sou portuguesa e ouvi isso com os meus próprios ouvidos. Se tratarem por Senhor ou Senhora dizem que eles estão no céu. Eu nunca tratei as pessoas por você nem senhora. Uso a abreviação S. Bárbara, por exemplo. Parece que se esquecem do seu significado. Vai-se lá entender. Eu apenas falo tipo, com licença, sabe isto? Apenas um exemplo. Falo os verbos sem a pessoa. Não parecem notar. E quando preciso me dirigir a alguém mais diretamente, falo consigo. É preciso ter um jogo de cintura e saber qual a forma mais recetiva para cada pessoa.

Comment: Por que não usas "vós"?

Comment: Porque isso era usado antigamente. Não se usa mais. Agora usamos o verbo da terceira pessoa no plural. Pouco a pouco creio que vão mudar para você. Não vejo mal nenhum nisso. Há apenas pessoas que ainda não aceitam, porque ainda estão habituadas ao que era. Na escola já aprendemos a falar na terceira pessoa do plural em vez da segunda - vós. Mas isso é muito pessoal. Eu ouvi pessoas a falarem assim, mas não é a minha maneira e não foi o que aprendi.

Answer (score 1):

O você em Portugal é usado como sujeito oculto pelo que tenho visto em Lisboa, Coimbra e Porto, além dos médias. Fala-se assim: "Agora que leu o termo de contrato, (você) deve assinar na linha pontilhada. Isto implica que (você) concorda com os termos presentes no presente documento".

Outra variação é o pronome do discurso indireto "si" no lugar de você:"Esta prenda é para si", "trazemos o melhor da notícia para si". Em Brsil, usa-se o "Si" precedido de um verbo no imperativo: "guarde para si", "faça isto para si".

O caso do uso do você no Brasil já está impregnado a nível vicioso, o voceísmo, que é a afirmação do verbo como ato praticado pela segunda pessoa, numa construção bizarra: "você me conhece", "Agora você tem a mitigaçao e a quarentena vertical e você tem a horizontal, você opta pela horizontal" (você ou as pessoas tomadoras de decisão?)

Comment: Como está oculto, não sabes se é *você* ou *o senhor*, que é muitas vezes o objetivo de o deixar oculto.

Answer (score 1):

Vivo em Portugal, mas minha lingua nativa é o espanhol.
Aqui falamos "você" para aqueles que não são portugueses, como os proveniente do Brasil.

Aqui usam "tu", "o senhor", "a senhora" ou simplesmente o nome do indivíduo, como "a Rita" e "o Pedro".

Um português não diz "você" porque é a maneira como a servidumbre (escravo) se dirigia ao senhor.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui onde eu moro, é muito comum usar tu, mas só com pessoas muito próximas, e com pessoas mais velhas senhor/senhora. Já com pessoas que não são tão próximas, em geral usamos o você, que é o mais normal.

Comment: Bem vinda ao site portugues.SE. Esta resposta tem um problem, não é dito em concreto  o lugar ou região em que o "você" é usado como a resposta diz. Quero alertar que por questões de privacidade poderá querer não identificar o local em particular -uma opção acoselhável que é deixada ao utilizador- mas nesse caso é preferível dizer, por exemplo: "em tal região é usado assim" sem particularzer que é o seu local de origem.

Answer (score 1):

Em Portugal é sempre preferível não utilizar a palavra "você" quando nos dirigimos a alguém, mesmo que o tratamento seja formal. É estranho mas é daquelas regras de cordialidade que não estão escritas em lado nenhum, mas que se assume como respeitosas das pessoas com quem nos relacionamos.

Há muitos portugueses que não percebem que o facto de nos dirigimos a alguém com a palavra você no discurso oral, não é cortez ou cordial junto de pessoas com quem não temos confiança suficiente para tratar por tu, mas será excessiva a utilização de senhor ou senhora.

Em Portugal, nunca encontrará um bom professor de português, ou algum especialista em comunicação, ou ainda, uma pessoa com elevada capacidade de escrita, utilizar a palavra você no discurso oral. Idealmente, criará uma ligação mais agradável, se suprimir a palavra você do discurso oral enquanto tratamos outra pessoa com um grau intermédio de formalidade.

Vamos supor esta situação: *"Gostava de saber cozinhar tão bem como você"*. Podemos dizer desta forma: *"gostava de ter a sua capacidade para cozinhar tão bem"*. Podemos também dizer assim: *"Gostava de saber cozinhar tão bem como a Fernanda o faz"* ou ainda: *"Gostava de saber cozinhar assim"*. São várias formas de dizer o mesmo sem nos colocarmos numa situação em que corremos o risco da outra pessoa se sentir desconfortável com a utilização da palavra você.

Por outro lado, a maioria dos portugueses sabe que o você no Brasil equivale ao tu em Portugal e quando um brasileiro trata um português por você, utilizando a palavra você, é tolerado de uma forma bastante diferente. Pessoalmente não gosto que se dirijam a mim por você, nem me dirijo a outras pessoas dessa forma, mas quando um brasileiro me trata por você, sendo eu português, aceito como um tu, porque conheço o contexto brasileiro de utilização dessa palavra. Por fim, é falta de educação um português dirigir-se a outro português utilizando a palavra você? Não, mas há melhores formas de o fazer, tal como referi anteriormente.

Answer (score -1):

A expressão «você é estrebaria» pode ajudar na resposta... Ver [artigo no Ciberdúvidas.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-expressao-voce-e-estrebaria/32198):

> Em Portugal, a forma de tratamento você nem sempre é considerada muito educada, e, ainda hoje, fora da intimidade, não é raro associá-la a alguém que não é muito culto e tem falta de educação.

Comment: Filipe, podes copiar o trecho relevante do link que postaste e adicionar na sua resposta? Isto impede que a resposta fique obsoleta caso o site linkado fique indisponível ou saia do ar no futuro.

Answer (score -1):

Se o uso de 'Você' é ofensivo em Portugal como dizem muitos aqui, é intrigante que na novela de Fernando Pessoa 'O Banqueiro Anarquista' o pronome 'Você' apareça 124 vezes.

Comment: Boa resposta, apesar que só encontrei "você" (ou "V." como Pessoa escreve) 89 vezes na obra: <https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/O_Banqueiro_Anarquista>. Porém, Fernando Pessoa faleceu há quase 100 anos atrás: isso não seria tempo suficiente para as conotações da palavra se alterarem?

Comment: Isto é uma conversa informal... hoje em dia usar-se-ia "tu", pelo menos entre pessoas com menos de 45 anos. É possível que as pessoas que  dizem que "você" não é ofensivo vivam em sítios em que de facto não é ofensivo, mas em Lisboa já várias vezes ouvi "você é a tua tia" e "você é estrebaria" em resposta a tratamentos por você.